# PowerShell script launched as administrator needs to run a command as logged on user

Tags: powershell, administrator

I have a long and detailed PowerShell script which I need to 'Run As Administrator' on a Windows Server. However towards the end of the script is the following...

```
$launchRDC = Read-Host "Launch Remote Desktop Connection to:" $hostname "as user:" $username "?(y/n)"
if ($launchRDC -eq 'y')
{
    #Launching MSTSC
    #Create credentials - Not working if Run As 'Administrator'
    cmdkey /generic:$hostname /user:JOLIETENT\$username /pass:$userPassword
    
    #Connect MSTSC with servername and credentials created before
    mstsc /v:$hostname
}
```

cmdkey is being used to store some credentials which I can then later take advantage of when calling mstsc to connect to a remote host. I have discovered that when the script is run as Administrator, it hangs on "cmdkey". However, when it is not run as Administrator, it works fine and I can later connect to the remote host via this automated call to mstsc without any problem. Of course I need to run the script as Administrator in order to achieve my other objectives.

I have done some investigation and it seems that cmdkey is one of those commands that needs a proper user context in which to run. Is there a way I can call cmdkey as the "Logged on user" within a PowerShell script launched as Administrator?

Thanks

Comment: You may run this part of the script using an [impersonation context](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity.impersonate?view=netframework-4.8). So most of the script run as administrator and this one is executed in the context of the impersonated user. .NET code must be translated a bit to PS but not so much work.

Comment: Would [RunAsUser](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/RunAsUser/2.2) from the PowerShell Gallery solve your issue?